# AWS on forge can't make a post request

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have recently provisioned my first site on AWS + Laravel Forge.

I can connect to mysql gui fine, hardcode some data and make a get request

But when I try to create a new user I get a 500 error

By default my forge DB_HOST is set to "127.0.0.1" but if I change it to my AWS IP, as I have done with a site hosted on Digital Ocean with Forge, it won't deploy.

When DB_HOST=AWS_IP

error =

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from information  
  _schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations)
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to manually create a MySQL RDB on AWS, or is forge doing that for me? I have migrated my tables and created data successfully..new to this so hope someone can help me out here (also my first post, hello!)

PS. can someone with the xp create a laravel-forge tag?

Cheers

Comment: What did Laravel support say about this?

Comment: Awaiting response. Referenced this Q in the support ticket and asked for improved instructions. Following this tutorial mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-forge-hosting-on-aws a follow up on data security and config would be a great help

Comment: I see `mysql` is the database, have you changed the `bind-address` parameter in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and tried?

Comment: my etc dir does not have a mysql component. Didn't have to edit that when I set up a server on digital ocean